# MySQL syntax error in SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, select, syntax

My code:

```
$fileid = $_GET['imgid'];
$fileid = (int)$fileid; //id is int type in photos table

require 'database.php';

//get the image sourc name

$q = "SELECT src form photos WHERE id='$fileid'";
$result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if ($result) 
{
    $row = $result->fetch_object();
    $filename = $row->src;
```

**ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'photos WHERE id='12'' at line 1**

Answer (score 5):

You have `FROM` misspelled. Try:

```
$q = "SELECT src FROM photos WHERE id='$fileid'";
```

---

<strike>In addition, while not related to this syntax error, note that your code appears to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).</strike>

Comment: it only appears to be, until you look at line 2 ;)

Comment: @Col: Oops, you're right. Didn't notice it's being cast to an `int`.

Comment: @Col. Yep the cast to int will prevent that whether by accident or design.